# storyboard navigation controller without tableview controller

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Whenever I add a Navigation controller to the xcode storyboard there is a tableviewcontroller added with a "relation" connecting the two and I don't want a tableviewcontroller, I want a regular viewcontroller. How do I get that? I am trying to reproduce the following Apple PhotoPicker sample in a storyboard.

[image: Apple PhotoPicker sample]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Easy:
Drag a ViewController onto the storyboard, then click "editor" and "embed in". Choose NavigationController.
Done.

Comment: Easy if you know where to click. Virtually impossible if no-one on the internet has written it down.